# Передача списка представления ToPagedList

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, mvc

Решил воспользоваться PagedList.Mvc для начала на примере, но проблема возникает при нажатия на любой номер странице. Изначально загружается все отлично а вот при нажатие ошибка.

> The view 'UpdateBlockNews' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Модель:

```
[Table("PageNews")]
public class PageNews
{
    [Key]
    public IPagedList<PrimaryNews> _BlocksNews = default(IPagedList<PrimaryNews>);
    public List<News> _FullPageNews = new List<News>();
    public MenuPanelNews _MenuNews = new MenuPanelNews();
    public List<News> FullPageNews
    {
        get { return _FullPageNews; }
        set { _FullPageNews = value; }
    }
    public PagedList.IPagedList<PrimaryNews> BlocksNews
    {
        get { return _BlocksNews; }
        set { _BlocksNews = value; }
    }
    public MenuPanelNews MenuNews
    {
        get { return _MenuNews; }
        set { _MenuNews = value; }
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult UpdateBlockNews(Models.PageNews _pageNews, int? page)
{
    int pageSize = 3;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    phones = new List<Models.PrimaryNews>();
    phones = IM.GetSqlData();
    _pageNews.BlocksNews = phones.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return View(_pageNews);
}
```

Представление:

```
@model Models.PageNews
<div>
    <div>
        @{
            Models.PageNews _pageNews = new Models.PageNews();
            Controllers.NewsController dataControllerNews = new Controllers.NewsController();
            _pageNews = dataControllerNews.UpdateMenuNews(_pageNews, null, null);
        {
......
        Page @(_pageNews.BlocksNews.PageCount < _pageNews.BlocksNews.PageNumber ? 0 : _pageNews.BlocksNews.PageNumber) of @_pageNews.BlocksNews.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(_pageNews.BlocksNews, page => Url.Action("UpdateBlockNews", new {_pageNews, page }))
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема возникает при использовании какого-то конкретного nuget-пакета, поэтому стоило бы указать, какой именно PagedList.MVC имеется ввиду (url на гитхаб или на nuget.org). Этих пакетов очень много, все разные. Некоторые из них при переходе на гитхаб имеют надпись "этот пакет deprecated и не поддерживается". С пакетами для asp.net core раньше была другая проблема, поэтому лично я устал подбирать нормально работающий и написал себе сам так, как мне нужно и не знаю, как сейчас. Попробуйте кстати взять другой пакет, возможно с ним повезёт больше.

Comment: А вид (файл UpdateBlockNews.cshtml) у вас есть?

Comment: От NuGet PagedList.Mvc, нет такого файла UpdateBlockNews.cshtml я передаю данные  return View(_pageNews) да же в примере Учебника Microsoft указываются только данные для передачи return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));